# access members of a structure from void pointer inside a structure

Tags: c

I want to access members of a structure from void pointer inside a structure, I have tried the following code but it is giving error as "expected identifier before ‘(’ token". what should I change in printf statement? Thanks in advance.

```
#include "stdio.h"
struct
{
    int date;
    char *name;
}test;

struct
{
    void *check;
}massage;

main()
{
    test.date=21;
    test.name="Nilesh";
    massage.check =&test;
    printf("date - %d , name - %s\n",massage.((struct test *)check)->date,massage.((struct test *)check)->name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct  // anonymous struct type 
{
    int date;
    char *name;
} test;
```

The above statement defines an anonymous struct type and creates a variable `test` of this struct type which has no name. Similarly, the below statement defines an anonymous struct type and creates a variable `massage` of this type -

```
struct  // anonymous struct type
{
    void *check;
} massage;
```

The typecast operator must have a type in the parentheses `(type)`, not a variable name. Therefore, you must give the first `struct` a  name (tag) so as to use the typecast operator. **Also, the result of a typecast operator is an `r-value` and therefore it cannot be used with member selection `.(dot)` operator (it should be the name of the member). Therefore, the typecast operator should be applied after the value is fetched from the structure.** Therefore, the following expression is wrong -

```
massage.((struct foo *)check)->date
//      |____________________|
//                |
//       this should be the member name but it
//       evaluates to a r-value - the result of
//       the typecast operator assuming struct tag
//       is foo

// it should instead be
((struct foo *)massage.check)->date
// dot operator has higher precedence than typecast
// so the struct member check is fetched first and 
// it is typecast to type (struct foo *)
```

I suggest the following changes -

```
// standard headers should be 
// enclosed in angle < > brackets
#include <stdio.h>

// give the structure a name so it can be 
// used in typecasting
struct foo {  
    int date;
    char *name;
} test;

// anonymous struct type
struct {
    void *check;
} massage;

// return type of main should be int and 
// parameter list should contain void
int main(void) {
    test.date = 21;
    test.name = "Nilesh";
    massage.check = &test;

    // fetch the struct member check and then 
    // apply typecast operator
    printf("date - %d , name - %s\n", ((struct foo *)massage.check)->date, 
                                      ((struct foo *)massage.check)->name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. I got exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

In your expression:

```
massage.((struct test *)check)->date
//               ^^^ is variable not a data-type
```

there are two mistakes:

1. You can't type case into a variable, in your code `test` is a variable not a type so `(struct test *)` is wrong expression. You should  name the user-defined type (as I have suggested below).
2. You are applying typecasting without accessing  `massage`'s pointer member. So in expression `(struct test *)check`, actually "check" is unknown variable. compiler will error you "check" is undeclared variable (thought `test` is not a datatype but the order of applying type casting is conceptually wrong).

I am suggesting a couple of correction try with it:

1. Name the stuct  e.g. `newtype`

   ```
    struct newtype  // notice I given name to user defined datatype
    {
       int date;
       char *name;
    }test;
   ```
2. Then correct second and third argument in printf function as below

   ```
     ((struct newtype *)massage.check)->date
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ notice
   ```

Similarly third argument in printf. First access member then type cast to correct type.

For full code refer Ajay's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23178861/1673391).

Comment: `test` here is a `struct` variable, not a `struct` tag. Can it be used for typecasting?

Answer (score 0):

The struct definition is not want you want -- it defines an object test of an unnamed struct type. Try

```
struct testType
{
    int date;
    char *name;
} test;
```

and then cast to (testType *).